# Rails generated query error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I have a scope in my `Rule` model using a HABTM relationship joining the `Room` and `Rule` models.

```
# rule.rb
scope :in_room, -> (room) { where(rooms: room) }
has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms

# schema.rb
create_table "rooms_rules", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "room_id"
    t.integer "rule_id"
end
```

And this piece of code:

```
Rule.in_room(Room.all.first)
```

Produces the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'rules.rule_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `rules`.* FROM `rules`  WHERE `rules`.`rule_id` = 1
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug in the ORM?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: List all rules that apply to this room.

Comment: The scope should be on the `room` model then. If all is setup correctly, doing `@room = Room.find(1)` `@room.rules` should work.